# How to to use .LastWriteTime and (Get-Date).Month to move data into a new Year/Month Folder Structure

Tags: powershell

I am fairly new to powershell and have been tasked at cleaning up an archive server. I am trying to create a script to move files into a Year\Month folder structure by looking at it's LastWriteTime in Powershell.

I have the below however I do not know how to get it to look at the month the file was edited?

```
$Path = "D:\Data"
$NewPath = "D:\ArchiveData"
$Year = (Get-Date).Year
$Month = (Get-Date).Month

New-Item $NewPath\ -name $CurrentYear -ItemType Directory
New-Item $NewPath\$Year -Name $Month -ItemType Directory
Get-ChildItem -path $Path | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -Contains (Get-Date).month} | Move-Item -Destination "$NewPath\$Year\$Month"
```

Any ideas of how I could do this would be appreciated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-contains` is used to see if an array contains an item; it's not suitable here.

`-eq` is what you need. As per your variable `$Month`, you will need to get only the part you care about (i.e. the month):

```
($_.LastWriteTime).Month -eq (Get-Date).month
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would approach this from the other end. Directories can be created when needed.

When you are satisfied that the files would be moved correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` cmdlet.

```
$Path = 'C:\src\t'
$NewPath = 'C:\src\tarch'

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Path |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Year = $_.LastWriteTime.Year
        $Month = $_.LastWriteTime.Month
        $ArchDir = "$NewPath\$Year\$Month"

        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $ArchDir)) { New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path $ArchDir | Out-Null }
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $ArchDir -WhatIf
    }
```